# Redirecting to another page after sign in with google - Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

Everything is working fine. Sign in with google is working.
I want to know what I need to add in my googlesignin function so that after sign in with google, it is redirected to facebook.html page?

Button code
`<button onclick="googleSignin()">Google Signin</button>`

```
 function googleSignin(){
   base_provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
   firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(base_provider).then(function(result){
      console.log(result)
      console.log("Success.. Google Account Linked")
   }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
      console.log("Failed to do")
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I would like to share with everyone.

```
function googleSignin(){
   base_provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
   firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(base_provider).then(function(result){ 
     window.location="facebook.html";
      console.log(result)
      console.log("Success.. Google Account Linked")
   }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
      console.log("Failed to do")
   })
}
```